# Change in size in Excel generation

Tags: java, excel, excel-2007

I have created a very large Excel file using poi library in java. When I open the Excel file and save it without making any changes, the files shrinks to about half of its original size. I know it may be because:

Excel performs optimizations to reduce file size when possible, but poi does not. How can I use this compression while creating file using java?

Comment: how was the file initially created  - post your code

Comment: File is created through java code.   WorkBook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream, true); At last it is converted to byte array and saved to table

Comment: It is generating a file of size 7 MB. I downloaded and opened it .Without any edited I just saved it .Then the file size reduced to 2.4 Mb

Comment: without code i can just guess. you probably created a .xls file - opened in ms excel and saved it as .xlsx file - this reduced the file size. If you want to create a .xlsx file directly, look in to the poi docs

Comment: XSSFWorkbook class is compatable for both xls and xlsx right. S I specified a xlsx template in fileinputstream       XSSFWorkbook newTitle = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103064/discussion-between-akhil-sudhakaran-and-balaji-krishnan).